# SQL Server query result to Excel file

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ssis

On Visual Studio, I have created a data flow task with OLE DB Source and Excel Destination.

Currently, data flow works fine but data formatted as numbers in database is copied as text in the Excel file.

1. I have tried to change column format but nothing changed
2. I have input a number in the specific column, refresh the connection to get the column formatting and erase the number from the file. Running the data blow again, data pass in the Excel the column formatted as number correctly but the first column remains empty (the column which has the number before deleted).

Any suggestions on how to import the data in the Excel file, in the correct format without the empty line?

Comment: SSIS works and doesn't need any tricks to export to Excel. We can't guess what your SSIS package does or even what `copied as text` means. Numbers look the same as text in Excel, in fact Excel will convert any *text* that looks like a number into a number. You actually have to do extra work to keep it as text by adding a single quote at the front. When you do that the cell is marked with a triangle marker at the top left.  How numbers are re *displayed* depends on the cell's style and local settings. The same number will appear differently in China and France

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the issue is that everything imported in the Excel file formatted as  text even the numbers. What i m trying to do is to import the data in the Excel as are formatted in SQL Server Table.